# Android Layout with ListView

Tags: android, listview, button, alignment

I am really getting frustrated with the layout as shown below:

[image]

I would like to have listview and below that I need to have two buttons side by side as shown above(LIstview should be scrollable and buttons should be as bottom bar ie..ontop tof the listview ). I have tried using  `android:layout_above` and   `android:layout_below` but nothing worked.Can anyone gimme an idea how to achieve this layout ?

This is what my layout code as of now  actually I have this code where I am able to achieve this but I'm unable to click the buttons here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/redbutton"
        android:onClick=""
        android:text="Previous"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/redbutton"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it is working on device. even the click is  working. which android version are you using. I tested on 4.4 and 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Get rid of the useless `LinearLayout` wrapping your `ListView`, moving the `android:padding` attribute into the `ListView`.

Step #2: Add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_above="@+id/firstLayout` to the `ListView`.

Step #3: Get rid of `android:layout_above="@id/secondLayout"` from the remaining `LinearLayout`, as you definitely do not want that above the `ListView`.

Step #4: Switch from `dp` to `sp` for your `Button` dimensions, to take into account font scaling.

Step #5: Either change the width of the `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content` or remove the `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`, as you cannot center something that fills all available space.

Off the cuff, the rest should be OK, or at least be a lot closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding the buttons to your actionbar?

Otherwise wrap the ListView inside an [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and make your RelativeLayout to LinearLayout

Comment: Do not put a `ListView` in a `ScrollView`. Even if that worked, it would not solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/firstLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick=""
            android:text="Previous"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working. What problem are you facing exactly?

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#00ffff"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:onClick="test"
        android:text="Previous"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="test"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @rachit-I am unable to click the buttons and coming to the layout if without the listview and with simple buttons I'm able to click them but when I add listview to the layout the list when loading from external class dosent make my button clickable and tested in 4.4

Comment: @coder, don't know man. I can't regenerate the issue. seems to be working on my device. click also working. :O :(